# Git bring changes from one feature branch to another feature branch

Tags: git, github

I have 2 feature branches A and B (where B was branched from A and not main).

I want to bring my latest changes that I made in A to the branch B.

I have tried (locally) checking out B and making git pull but it says that the branch is up to date with A.

Any ideas, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while in B, `git merge A` or `git rebase A`, depending on which strategy you're using.